# How to align English Arabic Text inside div?

Tags: html, css, text

I have text that contains English Arabic words and I am trying to align them correctly.

Here is the original text:
[image]

and here is what I get: 
[image]

```
I have used  css direction {rtl ltr Bidi}
```

with no luck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Mooseman  http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLvy/

Comment: That fiddle doesn't seem complete.  The CSS is unrelated to the HTML you have in there.  Can you update it?

Comment: @EliGassert I am so sorry now it works know

Comment: Is it me, or is neither the source in the fiddle, nor its result, the same as the "original text" in your question?

Comment: @MrLister the same problem occur when I paste the text in fiddler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine here when you apply `direction:rtl` to the right `id`. Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLvy/2/